# iOS app in Swift -- UITextView

Tags: ios7, swift, uitextview

I'm building an iOS app in Swift and want to be able to tap on a UITextView, and instead of the cursor selecting where to edit text, I’d like to make the keyboard disappear (resign the first responder).

Comment: Hmm, doesn't the keyboard pop up when you click in the text field?  I am unsure of what you are trying to do.  Can you explain more?

Comment: I would like the keyboard to disappear on a second user click instead of changing the position of the cursor within the text box.

Comment: I have it set now to hide keyboard on tap outside of the text box, but i need some cool way to hide it when folks tap anywhere, including in the text box while editing